# git error :Unable to look up xyz.com (port <none>) (Servname not supported for ai_socktype)

Tags: git

I'm getting this error message from git.What's this mean ? How to fix?

Comment: It'd be easier to give answers if you had simply copy-and-pasted your command with error in one piece. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this is related to Git, but rather linked to the server on which Git is running.

See [this article](http://www.ducea.com/2006/09/11/error-servname-not-supported-for-ai_socktype/)

> what could this mean: “Servname not supported for ai_socktype“.
>   After some other tries I have finally seen the problem… NTP ports were not defined in `/etc/services` and this was the root of the error.
>   The system didn’t know how to make ntp connections without that. So I’ve added the following lines to `/etc/services`

```
ntp             123/tcp
ntp             123/udp
```

> and after this `ntpdate` started working as expected…

Check with your administrator before attempting any modification of those files (unless this is your personal server)

Answer (score 3):

I do not think ntp issue has a bearing to the git error; at least in my case.

Here is my case:

```
xxxx@cerberus:~/src$ git clone git://http://cgit.sukimashita.com/sbmanager.git/tree sbmanager
Cloning into sbmanager...
fatal: Unable to look up http (port <none>) (Servname not supported for ai_socktype)
```

The problem was my syntax for git.

Here is my solution:

```
xxxx@cerberus:~/src$ git clone git://git.sukimashita.com/sbmanager.git sbmanager
Cloning into sbmanager...
remote: Counting objects: 764, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (643/643), done.
remote: Total 764 (delta 449), reused 257 (delta 118)
Receiving objects: 100% (764/764), 291.75 KiB | 261 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (449/449), done.
```

I think the solution is to check the syntax for git.