# unable to look up https fatal error when push to git repository

Tags: git, bash, shell

in git bash, I got a fatal error when try to push to a remote repository.

```
fatal:unable to look up https (port <none>)  (here with some unrecognized character %#^%)
```

in git shell, besides the fatal error I listed above, it occurs another warning

```
waring: Your console font probably doesn't support unicoode. if you experience strange characters in the output, consider switching to a Truetype font such as Lucida Console
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the syntax of the url is actually an https one (as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4551737/6309)):

```
git remote -v
```

It should be:

```
https://servername<:port>/repo
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same error and change https to ssh solved my problem