# fatal: Unable to look up bitbucket.org

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am new in git. I want to use bitbucket.org. I have setuped everythings in bitbucket and android studio. Now when I am trying to push my project by typing this command `git push -u origin master` it shows me this message `fatal: Unable to look up bitbucket.org (port tushar_shah) (The specified class was not found. )` How can I solve this? I have searched this in google. But could not find somethings helpful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [unable to look up https fatal error when push to git repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24469248/unable-to-look-up-https-fatal-error-when-push-to-git-repository)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the syntax of your repository url

```
git remote -v
```

Pay attention to the 'port' used in the url (seems you have used your username as a value for the port) The result may be something like

```
https://my-server:1234/repos/my-project.git
```

Normally the repository providers use the default ports, in which case you do not need to specify the port.

To change the url

```
git remote set-url origin https://my-server/repos/my-project.git
```

In your case

```
git remote set-url origin git://bitbucket.org/converter.git
```

For more info about protocols and urls in git, see https://git-scm.com/book/ch4-1.html

Comment: worked. But needed a little help from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333836/git-clone-cant-resolve-proxy. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the steps what I had to do:

`git remote set-url origin https://bitbucket.org/tushar_shah/*****.git`

`git config --global --unset http.proxy`

After that it was worked fine.